# SQLite combo-request with concatenating results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I use SQLite, and i want to create request for such option.

I have two tables A, B.
In A records contain field `id` with integers, and some field with string, for example `name`

In table B i have columns with names:

```
number A<name1> A<name2> A<name3>...
```

I need to get `number` from table B, where field `A<nameK>` equal to some value, where  is `name` for `id` in table A.
So i know `id` for A and i want to know `number` from B.

So i have 2 requests.

```
SELECT name as my_name FROM A WHERE id=<value>;
```

And after this i want something like that:

```
SELECT number FROM B WHERE A||my_name = <value>;
```

( || - i mean concatenacting of strings), but it's not work:(

Update - example of tables structures:

A:

```
id name
1   a 
2   b
3   c
```

B:

```
number Aa Ab Ac
10      1  2  3
11      4  5  6
12      7  8  9
```

So for example `id=2`, value in `B=5`, `name=b`, column name in B is `Ab`. Result `number=11`

`id=3, value=6`. Result `number=11`

`id=3, value=4`. Result `no result`

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your table structure, I highly assume that it is flawed. Just save `A<name>`'s `number` in individual rows, if necessary with an extra column for certain flags.